# Use Editor tools to add polygon from within ModelBuilder in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

Is it possible to activate the Editor tools from within ModelBuilder?

I have used ModelBuilder to create a new empty polygon layer, and I would like to trigger the editor tools to prompt the user to manually draw a polygon and add values to the attribute table, all from within ModelBuilder.

I've only been using ArcMap for a few hours (I usually use open source tools).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible in ModelBuilder. ModelBuilder only fires a geoprocessing tools one by one without breaks.

Logic of ArcGIS workflow is "not to break the flow". It means that if you run some processing it will work from start to end without any interactions with user.

You can extend AG functionality with add-ins (ArcObjects or pythonaddins). But the best way is to re-think your workflow. For example, you can start by drawing polygon and then fire up all the tools.